# Horizontal Menu with toggle on the right side

Tags: jquery, html, css, menu

I was browsing thenextweb and saw that social icons horizontal menu on the right side which have a toggle button

[image]

Does anyone knows how it's done?

Comment: There's no way to tell how it was implemented only from seeing a picture. There are literally an infinite number of ways this ***could*** have been done.

Comment: It's a combination of jquery and css to adjust the right margin of the icon bar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made a text version (without graphics) for your reference so you can start from there.

```js
$('#menu').click(function(){
 $('.nav-wrapper').toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
.nav-wrapper {
  list-style: none;
  float: right;
}

.nav-wrapper > li {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.nav {
  list-style: none;
  margin-right: -115px;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.nav-wrapper.active .nav {
  margin-right: 0;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.nav > li {
  float: left;
  width: 18px;
  margin: 0 5px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#menu::after {
  display: block;
  content: "OPEN";
  width: 60px;
  height: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.nav-wrapper.active > #menu::after {
  content: "CLOS"
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav-wrapper">
  <li>
    <ul id="nav-bar" class="nav">
      <li>L1</li>
      <li>L2</li>
      <li>L3</li>
      <li>L4</li>
      <li>L5</li>
      <li>L6</li>
    </ul>    
  </li>
  <li id="menu"><li>
</ul>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zayzw6es/

Comment: That's exactly what I needed to know (how it was done), thanks!